# regular expression to mask all but the last 4 digits of a social security number

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string

```
ssn = "166557649"
```

And I want to replace it as such:

```
ssn = "*****7649"
```

When I use curly braces and specify a limit, it unfortunately replaces all the digits with a single "*":

```
ssn.gsub(/\d{5}/,"*")
 => "*7649"
```

I am able to use square brackets to replace multiple digits but it ends up replacing all of them:

```
ssn.gsub(/[0-9]/,"*")
 => "*********"
```

I tried this as well:

```
ssn.gsub(/[0-9]{5}/,"*")
=> "*7649"
```

To clarify, I want to replace all but the last 4 digits. In other words, even if social security number had 20 digits (even though this will never happen), then it should replace the first 16 digits with asterick and just leave the last 4 visible.

Comment: **What do you mean by atmost 5 digits? A single example would not be enough**

Comment: @AvinashRaj the intention is to leave the last 4 digits of a social security number visible.

Comment: your question title does not suggest your intention

Comment: do you want to leave the last four digits from the above input only? Or do you have any other inputs?

Comment: Usually ssn have 9 digits but I cannot be sure of that. Therefore, I just want to mask all characters except the last 4.

Comment: You accepted an answer that does not answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?=\d{5})\d
```

Try this.This uses a positive lookahead to check for `5` digits.Replace by `*`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/12

Comment: Again, it's not my downvote, but this does not do what the OP asked for ("replace at most 5 digits" is different from "always leave 4 digits unreplaced").

Comment: Hm, `(?<!\d{5})\d` would be nicer.

Answer (score 6):

Why even use a regular expression? It makes it more complicated than it needs to be:

```
ssn = "166557649"
'*' * 5 + ssn[-4..-1]
=> "*****7649"
```

Simply extract the last four characters and append them to a string of five '*'.

People grab at using regular expressions too often without thinking about whether there is a simpler, faster, and easier to maintain way of doing the same thing.

"[Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)" is recommended reading.

---

As @CarySwoveland suggested, here's a tweak to handle alternate length SSN:

```
ssn = "166557649"
('*' * (ssn.size - 4)) + ssn[-4..-1] 
# => "*****7649"
```

Comment: Absolutely - well said!

Comment: I'd suggest one small change: replace `5` with `ssn.size-4` (as the OP made a reference to different size strings).

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I see from a comment that @AvinashRaj evidently posted this answer previously, but then took it down. I obviously don't see a problem with it.

I like @theTinMan`s answer best, but if a regex is used, you could write

```
"166557649".gsub(/\d(?=\d{4})/,'*') #=> "*****7649"
```

`(?=\d{4})` is a positive lookahead that demands that four (or more) digits follow, but are not part of the match.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a optional block to [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-sub) / [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub). The return value of the block is used as a replacement string:

```
ssn = "166557649"
ssn.sub(/\d{1,5}/) { |x| '*' * x.size }
# => "*****7649"
```

BTW, you need to use `{1,5}` instead of `{5}` if you want to match **at most 5** digits.

**UPDATE**

To masks characters except the **last 4 digits**:

```
ssn.sub(/.*(?=\d{4}$)/) { |x| '*' * x.size }
# => "*****7649"
```

The pattern matches characters followed by the last 4 digits. (using [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your regex captures all five digits on a single match, and that is replaced by the replacement string `"*"` at once.

Comment: Apparently the downvoter hasn't noticed that you actually answered the question as it was asked (but probably not as it was meant).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for noticing that. There are so many users on this site who cannot read.

Answer (score 0):

A working Excel VBA Function example that will mask the SSN anywhere within a string of text leaving the remaining 4-digits unmasked.

***Note:*** You must add "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" as a Reference (see Tools/Reference) for this to work.

```
Function ssnMask(ByVal strInput As Variant) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    'Mask SSN
    strPattern = "\d{3}-\d{2}-(?=\d{4})"
    strReplace = "XXX-XX-"
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    ssnMask = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
End Function
```